# Changing Backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Need to do a Fadein Background changing but my code doesn't work. Whats wrong?!

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fundoimg = 1;
    var carrossel = function () {
        if(fundoimg === 1) {
            var troca1 = $(".jumbotron").css("background-image","url('../images/bg1.png')");
            troca1.fadeIn("slow");
            fundoimg = 2;
        } else {
            var troca2 = $(".jumbotron").css("background-image","url('../images/bg2.png')");
            troca2.fadeIn("slow");
            fundoimg = 1;
        }
    }

    setInterval(carrossel,3000);
});
```

Here's my CSS code for this "JUMBOTRON":

```
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 17% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('../images/bg1.png');
}
```

And here's the row in the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/carrossel.js"></script>
```

At least but not last, my files tree:

```
projectfolder\index.html
projectfolder\css\style.css
projectfolder\images\*.png
projectfolder\scripts\*.js
```

What could be wrong?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Changing Automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327670/background-changing-automatically)

Comment: Try $(".jumbotron").animate({"background-image": "url('../images/bg1.png')}, 3000);

Comment: Why did you start a new question?

Comment: @MarceloLuz Didn't work.

Comment: @epascarello Everybody forgotten that topic. Could you please help me? It still doesn't work and neither my dropdown menu. I'm posting here the files, can you help me? [DOWNLOAD](https://mega.co.nz/#!usRg0Rqb!qvBWTqOd2TdacWS6xnb15Hi3nHLhJSF-gkaNcd-nURs)

Comment: Ok first thing i noticed when running firebug is that jQuery is not being recognized. add an alert to your carrosel function and youll see that its not actually being run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works so either your paths are wrong, your div is not there, it does not have a size, or the code is not on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fundoimg = 1;
    var carrossel = function () {
        if(fundoimg === 1) {
            var troca1 = $(".jumbotron").css("background-image","url('http://i.imgur.com/o5jk8hA.jpg')");
            troca1.fadeIn("slow");
            fundoimg = 2;
        } else {
            var troca2 = $(".jumbotron").css("background-image","url('http://i.imgur.com/ArSY9CS.jpg')");
            troca2.fadeIn("slow");
            fundoimg = 1;
        }
    }

    setInterval(carrossel,3000);
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 17% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/ArSY9CS.jpg');
  width:500px; height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you try looking in my files? I Put the download link up there in the comments. Pretty please!